# sort cell column by empty cells without reshaping cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, cell

I have a cell array composed of cells of different values and different numbers of elements and many empty cells. I would like to reorder each column of cells such that the empty cells are pushed to the last rows but without reordering non-empty cells.

(apologies for probably not writing this out the best way)
so cell:

```
[1,2,3] []      [1,4,2] []      []
[]      [1,2,5] []      []      [2,2,1]
[3,7,1] []      [1,1,1] [2,3,1] [1,2,2]
```

need this:

```
[1,2,3] [1,2,5] [1,4,2] [2,3,1] [2,2,1]
[3,7,1] []      [1,1,1] []      [1,2,2]
[]      []      []      []      []
```

is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cellfun` to loop through all elements and determine if a cell is empty, you can then sort the result (a logical matrix) along the first dimension. This will push all of the empty elements (`1`) to the last rows and leave the non-empty elements (`0`) at the top and won't alter their order since they are all of equal value (`1`).

```
data = {[1,2,3], [], [1,4,2],  [], [];
        [], [1,2,5], [], [], [2,2,1];
        [3,7,1], [], [1,1,1], [2,3,1], [1,2,2]};

% Create a logical matrix that is 1 where the empty elements are and sort the columns
[~, rows] = sort(cellfun(@isempty, data), 1);

% Convert to linear index and index into the original matrix to re-arrange
newdata = data(bsxfun(@plus, rows , size(data, 1)*(0:size(data, 2)-1)));

%   [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
%   [1x3 double]              []    [1x3 double]              []    [1x3 double]
%             []              []              []              []              []
```

Comment: Or a bit faster with `bsxfun` : `bsxfun(@plus,rows,nRows*(0:nCols-1))`.

Comment: @Divakar Great point. I knew there was a `bsxfun` solution somewhere, just hadn't spent time on it. I'll add that to the answer.